# FB Messenger Persistent Menu Nest within a nest?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I am having trouble getting a nested menu within a nested menu. Does anyone know if you can only go on level down? Or can you do two?

I have here a menu that is nested within a nest -- but I keep getting this error: 
{"error":{"message":"(#100) Requires one of the params: get_started,persistent_menu,target_audience,whitelisted_domains,greeting,account_linking_url,payment_settings,home_url","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"H1RDxO9wOcL"}}

Here is my code

```
"persistent_menu":[
>   {
>     "locale":"default",
>     "composer_input_disabled": false,
>     "call_to_actions":[
>       {
>         "title":" Menu",
>         "type":"nested",
>         "call_to_actions":[
>           {
>             "title":"About",
>             "type":"postback",
>             "payload":"ABOUT"
>           },
>           {
>             "title":"Tips",
>             "type":"nested",
>             call_to_actions":[    
>                     {
>                     "title":"Hours",
>                     "type":"postback",
>                     "payload":"Hours"
>                     },{
>                     "title":"Restroom",
>                     "type":"postback",
>                     "payload":"Restroom"
>                     },{
>                     "title":"Other",
>                     "type":"postback",
>                     "payload":"Other"
>                     },
>               ]
>           },
>           {
>             "title":"Leaderboard",
>             "type":"postback",
>             "payload":"Leaderboard"
>           }
>         ]
>       },
>     ]
>   }
> ]
> }' "https://graph.facebook.com
```

Answer (score 0):

POST to Messenger Profile API with your own Page Access Token. You should be page admin to do this.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

with following data

```
{"persistent_menu":[{"locale":"default","composer_input_disabled":false,"call_to_actions":[{"title":" Menu","type":"nested","call_to_actions":[{"title":"About","type":"postback","payload":"ABOUT"},{"title":"Tips","type":"nested","call_to_actions":[{"title":"Hours","type":"postback","payload":"Hours"},{"title":"Restroom","type":"postback","payload":"Restroom"},{"title":"Other","type":"postback","payload":"Other"}]},{"title":"Leaderboard","type":"postback","payload":"Leaderboard"}]}]}]}
```

I tested it on my own bot, hope this will work for you as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/persistent-menu

**Requirements for Persistent Menu:**

- Set a get started button.
- Have the 'Administrator' role for the page associated with the bot.

If you didn't create any **get_started** button, you should create one like below curl request. get_started button is a requirement to create a persistent_menu.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ 
  "get_started":{
    "payload":"START_PAYL"
  }
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=<API_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

If you already have a get_started button, now you can run below curl request to create **persistent_menu**:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "persistent_menu":[
    {
      "locale":"default",
      "composer_input_disabled": true,
      "call_to_actions":[
        {
          "title":"My Account",
          "type":"nested",
          "call_to_actions":[
            {
              "title":"Pay Bill",
              "type":"postback",
              "payload":"PAYBILL_PAYLOAD"
            },
            {
              "title":"History",
              "type":"postback",
              "payload":"HISTORY_PAYLOAD"
            },
            {
              "title":"Contact Info",
              "type":"postback",
              "payload":"CONTACT_INFO_PAYLOAD"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type":"web_url",
          "title":"Latest News",
          "url":"http://www.messenger.com/",
          "webview_height_ratio":"full"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "locale":"zh_CN",
      "composer_input_disabled":false,
      "call_to_actions":[
        {
          "title":"Pay Bill",
          "type":"postback",
          "payload":"PAYBILL_PAYLOAD"
        }
      ]    
    }
  ]
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=<API_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

**Important Note:** An array of top-level menu items for the persistent menu. **A maximum of 3 items is allowed.** **A maximum of two nested menus are supported.**

Answer (score 0):

You can quickly resolve this issue and more by using Botsnacks. https://github.com/4handheld/botsnacks . 
Everything is automated including the get started payload , menu and more.